# I can't access page using http-server

Tags: angular

I tried to access the page using http-server -p 8081 but the browser said "No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:8081/app/home"

I run ng build --prod and go to dist folder and run http-server -p 8081

root-routing.module.ts has

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/app/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'account', loadChildren: 'account/account.module#AccountModule', data: { preload: true }
},
{
    path: 'app',
    loadChildren: 'app/app.module#AppModule', 
    data: { preload: true }
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: []
})
export class RootRoutingModule { }
```

How can I access my home page? Do I miss anything?

Comment: Does it serve http://localhost:8081/ correctly ? (without home).  

EDIT : Shouldn't the link you're trying to access be : http://localhost:8081/app/home ?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I accessed localhost:8081 and redirect to app/home But still can't access

Comment: Does other routes work?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, to my understanding `http-server` does not supports serving SPA, at least not if you open directly an url to a specific page. Instead it will try to serve the file at the given path. For instance: `/home/hello` won't be resolved to your angular's router path but instead try to serve `/home/hello/index.html` which is likely not found

To prevent this issue, I used [angular-http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-http-server)

```
npm install -g angular-http-server
cd /path/to/site
angular-http-server
```

Answer (score 0):

I found http-server has a problem. I installed http-server@0.9.0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you named your project wrongly:

```
http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist/<project-name>
```

Check your dist folder to see what the name of your app is. Most likely just "app".